# How to rewrite the url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How could I rewrite [www.nano.com](http://www.nano.com)

to

[www.nano.com/nano/index.php](http://www.nano.com/nano/index.php)
or 
[www.nano.com/nano/](http://www.nano.com/nano/)

Comment: With what method? .htaccess, PHP, etc.

Comment: go and try yourself first.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nano/$ index.php [L]
```

**Edited**

If you want to access your sub folder so you have to make htaccess file like below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nano/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nano/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ nano/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I used this method to edit the '.htaccess', but when I enter the 'www.nano-channel.com' the web displays that'Directory Listing Denied'. I don't know how to do, now I have to redirect the page, but I would like to use '.htaccess' to rewrite the url. could you give me some advice?

Comment: @Taylor just put that code in your htaccess file and you can test it  `yourdomain.com/nano/`

Comment: The **yourdomain.com/nano/** works, but the **yourdomain.com** still doesn't work. Actually, my web server is in **\wwwroot\**, my web project is in the **\wwwroot\nano\**. So **yourdomain.com** will access the **\wwwroot\**, however I want to use the **.htaccess** to rewrite **yourdomain.com** to **yourdomain.com\nano\** to access the `\wwwroot\nano\`.  Thanks you.